# In React 18 SSRProvider is not necessary and is a noop. You can remove it from your app, how to resolve this warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

Hello people im getting this error in react native
In React 18, SSRProvider is not necessary and is a noop. You can remove it from your app
I have tried this @react-aria/ssr and used  instead of , but not resolved the warning. any suggestions would be helpful.

Im using react 18.2.0, native base ^3.4.28, react native 0.71.8.

below is my code in App.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <NativeBaseProvider theme={theme}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#292929'}}>
        <StatusBar
          translucent
          backgroundColor="#292929"
          barStyle="light-content"
        />
        <AppNavigation />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  </Provider>
```

I have tried this @react-aria/ssr and used  instead of , but not resolved the warning. any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I initiated a fresh project, where I only installed nativebase, and I'm coming across the identical problem.

Comment: Check this many has this issue https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/5758

Answer (score 15):

1. Navigate to `node_modules/native-base/src/core/NativeBaseProvider.tsx`.
2. Delete the `<SSRProvider></SSRProvider>` that wraps `{children}`. Take care not to delete `{children}`.
3. Remove the `SSRProvider` import. That is, delete this line: `import { SSRProvider } from '@react-native-aria/utils';`.
4. Run `npx patch-package native-base`. Select 'yes' in the prompt.

When Native Base officially fixes it, you can delete the patch from the patch directory that was created and reinstall native-base

> https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/5758

Comment: I would prefer to not touch third party package code. Changes there might not work in release deploy, when the packages are fetched from original source. Also any changes under node_modules-folder are ignored by git by default. You would need to have a workaround for that too. But in this specific case this won't show up in release version as it is only warning. You can ignore it with the logbox but that is only hiding it. Real fix is to release a fix to the native-base package.

Comment: NativeBase was deprecated. They released gluestack framework

Comment: If you have both Yarn and npm installed in your development environment, you can utilize the following command to apply the patch for the 'native-base' package using npx: 

npx patch-package native-base --use-yarn

Comment: There is now a prop called `isSRR` that we can set to `false`

Answer (score 1):

for me I added this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(['In React 18, SSRProvider is not necessary and is a noop. You can remove it from your app.']);
  }, []);
```

Don't forget to import {LogBox} from 'react-native';

Comment: This will not resolve the warning, instead, it will just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Here the fix of
In React 18 SSRProvider is not necessary and is a noop. You can remove it from your app.

goto project directory
\node_modules\native-base\src\core\NativeBaseProvider.tsx

replace NativeBaseProvider.tsx file code
to
https://gist.github.com/VagnerSilva/974227ead2359c0362a7b4173cb5a729#file-nativebaseprovider-tsx
with this code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. In Linux terminal:

> cd ./node_modules/native-base/src/core

For windows: open the 'core' directory

2. Open NativeBaseProvider.tsx
3. Find SSProvider, It may look like below:

> `<SSRProvider>{children}</SSRProvider>`

4. Change that line from that to the line given below:

> `{children}`

5. Save, Than reload React Native App
6. Note: Remove  `<SSRProvider></SSRProvider>`
   Don't even keep it as comment.

:)